# ionic serve uncaught exception

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I am running ionic serve nothing shows in my web browser

```
ionic serve
```

And this is what I receive:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:myDemoApp mona$ ionic serve
The port 35729 was taken on the host localhost - using port 35730 instead
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35730
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $ An uncaught exception occured and has been reported to Ionic



listen EADDRINUSE (CLI v1.5.0)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.5.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.1.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Mavericks
Node Version: v0.10.24
Xcode version: Xcode 6.2 Build version 6C131e
```

what's the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: make sure to close all ionic apps opened in the browser first, and the CLI related to them

Comment: The CLI still is in development and contains bugs; so that may be causing the error. Could you try going back to version `1.4.5` just to be sure that it's nothing on your end? Use `npm` for that: `npm install -g ionic@1.4.5`

Answer (score 5):

listen EADDRINUSE (CLI v1.5.0) means the adress is in use.

please go on terminal and try "killall ionic" to kill running ionic processes on the port and restart the server with "ionic serve".